# Run a library on R while having the data in a different folder

Tags: r

I have a very simple question I'm sure, but I can't find the solution, please someone help me!

I installed MixSIAR for R, which is a package for statistical analysis and I see that the library is in C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/MixSIAR and the script works perfectly as long as my data is in the same folder MixSIAR, but if I want to have it in my Dropbox or any other folder in my PC it doesn't work, because I can't figure out how to write the path to "call" the package MixSIAR.

```
#library(MixSIAR) # Works but needs data to be in the same MixSIAR folder.
 library("C:/Users/pingry/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/MixSIAR") # doesn't work

# Load consumer
mix.filename <- system.file("data", "contemp_turtles_Oahu_consumer.csv", package = "MixSIAR")
mix <- load_mix_data(filename=mix.filename,
           iso_names=c("d13C","d15N","d34S"),
           factors=NULL,
           fac_random=NULL,
           fac_nested=NULL,
           cont_effects=NULL)
```

The error I get:

Error is in library("C:/Users/pingry/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/MixSIAR") :
there is no package called ‘C:/Users/pingry/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/MixSIAR’

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJn2B.png)

Comment: Just use `library(MixSIAR)`. You should not have a full file path in a `library()` call. Do not use `system.file()` to load your own data. That's just for sample data that comes with the project. you should not put any files in your win-library folder yourself. Instead, change `mix.filename` to the path of the file you want to use. By default, R will look in the current working directory (you can check that value with `getwd()`).

Comment: @MrFlick thank you so much! It's working great now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr. Flick gave me the answer so here is the code fixed to have my data in my Dropbox and use the MixSIAR package:

```
library(MixSIAR)
# Load mix data
mix <- load_mix_data(filename=("data/contemp_turtles_2islands_consumer.csv"),
           iso_names=c("d13C","d15N","d34S"),
           factors="island",
           fac_random=TRUE,
           fac_nested=FALSE,
           cont_effects=NULL)
```